# How to build a dynamic data table with backend fields for the user

Tags: table

Since i am very new to wordpress, what is the best way to create a custom dynamic data table that a user can add/modify or delete data from the backend?
what i need as a final table is something like:

- Logo(an image) | Brand(text) | offer(text) | link(text)

and pulled somewhere in the homempage. i tried to create a custom plugin, it seems a bit advanced for me, and don't actually know if it is what i am looking for. i also played with advanced custom fields but only managed to store each brand in a post instead of a row...

thank you in advance

EDIT: Yes you are right! ACF can do this using the repeater field
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Advanced Custom Fields Pro](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/pro/) lets you add an [options page](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/options-page/) to the WordPress backend. Then you can create your fields for site-wide options (i.e. logo, branding options, etc) on a dedicated options page and pull them from anywhere on the site, rather than only from within specific posts/post types.

Comment: thank you for that! i can see them using the option page feature for header and footer in their video... , so i sent them a mail. have you used ACF PRO in such way?i mean, for what i need it for .

Comment: Yes, I I use it for pretty much every WordPress project.